# Fastest way to SELECT through MySQL table records backwards from a certain row?

Tags: mysql, performance, select

With a table over 18 million rows:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id > 10000000 LIMIT 30
```

Took 0.0724 sec.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id < 10000000 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30
```

Took 0.0565 sec.

Is this the fastest way to SELECT certain number of records before a certain row in MySQL?

It seems good enough but doesn't MySQL have to first order those 10 million rows in descending order before SELECT-ing the 30 rows?

I'm asking this is because I'm not so sure of this query I came up. It does seem work and fast enough but looking at the grammatical semantics, I'm not so sure.

Is MySQL intelligent enough to know that it doesn't have to order all those 10 million rows?

Or is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: If you dont care which 30 rows before a certain id use the variant without ORDER BY,it SHOULD be faster..Besides if thats a primary key the rows are already ordered so in the second query you might get a range scan.Im not sure.Put an EXPLAIN before those queries and edit your question with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't have to order the rows *at all* if you have an index on the `id` column (or have it as the initial portion of the primary key).

It will simply *use* that index, giving already sorted data, and just grab the first thirty elements.

Yes, if it can't efficiently retrieve the rows in sorted order, it likely will have to get the lot and then sort. But that would be rather bad DBMS design.

Comment: Is that so for backwards SELECT like in `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30`? I thought indexes were only useful for the default order ASC?

Comment: @kavoir.com: a simple one-column index can be scanned in reverse order quite easily. You can run into issues with compound keys but that doesn't apply here.

Comment: InnoDB indexes are in a B+Tree structure.  That allows drilling into the tree to find one specific row, then linking to the 'next' or 'previous' row very efficiently.  Re: compound indexes:  `ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC` also works efficiently, but not `ORDER BY a ASC, b DESC`.